# Preservation of the complex structure in warped product

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M=N \times_fF$ a (real) warped product submanifold of a Kähler manifold $W$.
If $M$ does not preserve  the complex structure, is it possible that $N$ or $F$ preserve it? Or surely not even them?

And vice versa? If $M$ preserve the complex structure, is surely that also $N$ and $F$ preserve it?

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by "preserves the complex structure"? I'd understand it for a group acting by diffeomorphisms, but not in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I mean that $M$ is a real submanifold of $W$, then a complex structure is an endomorphism of the tangent bundle $J:TM\to TM$ such that $J^2=-1$ (it plays the role of the multiplication by $\sqrt{-1}$). Saying that a Riemannian metric $g$ preserves the complex structure amounts to saying that $g(Jv,Jv)=g(v,v)$ for all tangent vector $v$.

Comment: Is the metric on $M$ the induced metric from $W$ or is it completely unrelated?

Comment: @Michael Albanese - thank you! the metric is Riemannian